# Python Flask web scraping error when use proxy

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I'm getting photo url from Imgur with use a proxy which Imgur is banned in Turkey. I still get the requests.exceptions.ConnectionError. How can I do?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0'}
proxies = {
    'http': '104.32.43.13:53281',
    'https': '104.32.43.13:53281',
    }
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    source = requests.get('https://imgur.com/t/fall/WuL2IqJ',proxies=proxies, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'html.parser')
    url = soup.find('img',class_='post-image-placeholder')['src']
    urlT = url.text
    return render_template('home.html',**locals())
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Proxies could be dead

Comment: @MohitC I tried 30 proxies, they all give the same error

Answer (score 0):

Although its common for proxies to just be passed like `IP:PORT` or `USER:PASS:IP:PORT`, you need to reformat those proxies so that requests understands how to connect:

https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies

Your proxy dict should resemble:

```py
proxies={
    'http': 'http://0.0.0.0:0000',
    'https': 'https://0.0.0.0:0000'
}
```

Note that if you have user-pass authenticated proxies, they need to be reformatted like: `proxies = {'http': 'http://user:pass@10.10.1.10:3128/'}`